# PHP news system with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a news sytem in php.
The DB structure looks like this

```
"title"  "author"  "content"
```

And the PHP script looks like this

```
<?php   
include ('config2.php');

$result = mysql_query("select * from news");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$title = $row['title'];
$author = $row['author'];
$content = $row['content'];
}
echo"<div class=\"post\">
                <h2 class=\"title\"><font color=\'#1e1e1e\' href=\"#\">$title</font></h2>
  <p class=\"meta\">Today <a href=\"#\">$author</a></p>

                    <p>$content</p>
                    </ul>

  </div>"
 ?>
```

What I want to do is : Each time I insert a new row in my db, I want the new to be displayed on the page, and right now when I add a new row it just edit the previous new.
Any idea?

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions your are using are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future PHP versions. Don't write new code with them, use `myqsli_*` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `echo`ing outside the `while` loop. Modify it to the following:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $author = $row['author'];
    $content = $row['content'];
    echo"<div class=\"post\">
         <h2 class=\"title\"><font color=\'#1e1e1e\' href=\"#\">$title</font></h2>
         <p class=\"meta\">Today <a href=\"#\">$author</a></p>
         <p>$content</p>
         </ul>
         </div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `echo` statement **inside** the `while` loop.